# Changing value in csv file by searching for another value (Python)

Tags: python, csv, replace

Trying to change a csv file with python.
The items in the csv file are:[items in csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/culaH.png)

The goal is to select action "2", the program will ask you to input "bilanumer"(car number) and if you enter a car number from the csv file it will change the value of item[7] that belongs to that car number to "0D".
[how my program looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npcxp.png)

When I run the program it looks like it's working fine, judging by the "print(line)", but cvs file has't changed at all.
[output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRYNI.png)

what do I have to do to save the change I made to the csv file, or what am I doing wrong?
Note: the csv file could be hundreds of line long. Need to find a specific car by imputing it's car number and the program automatically changes (0D(skiladagur) ([7]) to "0D"

Thanks :)

Resolved:[Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA611.png)